# TailwindCSS - Padding and margin doesn't work on responsive breakpoints

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I am working on a responsive design using Tailwind CSS on nuxtjs.

Anyone here knows why py-8 is applying to both breakpoints?

This is how I am writing the component

```
<template>
  <div class="bg-[#EEEEEE] py-8 lg:py-20">
    <p class="text-3xl lg:text-5xl text-center mb-0">Partners</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

I am googling and stackoverflowing but the problem answers refers to old version of tailwind css using variants property on tailwind.config.js

Comment: What do you see in your browser's devtools? What is happening at `lg` breakpoint? Is the CSS property not taken into account, overwritten or alike?

Comment: What do you mean by applying to both breakpoints? Your code on the divs work as expected. See: https://play.tailwindcss.com/y8joAFy80T (resize the preview panel with the bar in the center). So it is not in the code you show or in the default Tailwind setup.

Comment: @kissu is overwritten

Comment: The mobile is overwritten or the desktop one? Mind providing a [repro]? Would greatly help us debug this.

Answer (score 0):

According the tailwindcss official documentation.
Breakpoint of `lg` is `1024px`

```
 'lg': '1024px',
      // => @media (min-width: 1024px) { ... }
```

The code is working just fine.
As the background is near to white you are not able to figure out the changes.

To ensure it is working try with the black background once . And change to the color you want .

**The code**:

```
<div class="bg-[#000000] py-8 lg:py-20">
  <p class="text-3xl lg:text-5xl text-center mb-0 text-green-500">
    Partners
  </p>
</div>
```

**The output**:

1. For screen size less the `lg` breakpoint
   [image]
2. For the screen size greater than `lg` breakpoint
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Well after facing this problem for about 2 months I finally find out that vuetify and tailwind css have some problems working together, if you are facing same problem and actually are using vuetify + tailwind css consider using prefix for tailwind classes

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#prefix